# Why when I press CTRL+C the program reads zero bytes? (C-Posix)

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, eof

My program has to do this:
The user has to pass N absolute pathname for files by command line. Then the i-th thread, with 0<=i<= N, has to write in the i-th file a string passed by user with scanf (or fgets). If CTRL+C is pressed, the program has to print all strings that user has passed with scanf.

When I run this and I insert a string for 1 of the N files and I press CTRL+C, in the function onPress the function read returns 0 (I think that in this case not indicates that the file pointer is in the end of file) and it prints only the string "Strings:"

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int fdGlobal;

void* writer (int* arg) {
   int fd_in = *(arg);
   char buffer[100];  
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   printf("Write the string that you want to insert in the file\n");
   scanf("%s", &buffer);
   write(fd_in, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
   write(fdGlobal, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
   printf("Finished\n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
}

void onPress(int sig) {
   char buff[100];
   printf("I'm going to print all strings passed in files...\n");
   int rd = read(fdGlobal, &buff, sizeof(buff));
   if (rd == -1) perror("Error in the read of global file\n");
   printf("I read %d bytes\n", rd);
   printf("Strings: %s\n", buff);
   exit(0);
}

void main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int fds[argc-1];
   pthread_t tid[argc-1];
   int i, mu;

   if (argc<=1) {
      printf("Insert a number >=1 of  pathname/s\n");
   }

   for ( i = 1 ; i<argc; i++) {
      if (argv[i][0] != '/') {
        printf("Insert a pathname\n");
       }
   }

   signal(SIGINT, onPress);

   fdGlobal = open("globalFile.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
   if (fdGlobal == -1) perror("Error in the open of global file\n"); 

   mu = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   if (mu < 0) perror("Error in the creation of mutex\n");

   for (i=0; i<argc-1; i++) {
      fds[i] = open(argv[i+1], O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0666);
      if (fds[i] < 0 ) perror("Error in the open of the file\n");

      pthread_create ( &tid[i], NULL, (void*) writer, &(fds[i]) );
   }

  for (i=0; i<argc-1; i++) {
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
  }
  }
```

Comment: *When I run this and I insert a string for 1 of the N files and I press CTRL+C*  Do you hit "Enter" before pressing `CTRL-C`?  If not, your process never reads the input.  Also, you can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from a signal handler. The list of POSIX async-signal-safe functions is at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03  Calling a function not on the list can invoke undefined behavior.  Additionally, `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Yes, I've also pressed Enter

Comment: What exactly is the point of creating a thread and then immediately `pthread_join`ing it?  This gives you no concurrency; it is almost equivalent to just calling the thread function (*i.e.* `writer()`) directly.

Comment: You are right. I revised my code. But the problem remains.

Comment: Potential problems: Not checking return code of `scanf`. Using `scanf` to read string without specifying target buffer size. Printing buffer you read with `read` without adding terminating `'\0'`. Using non-async-signal-safe functions in signal handler. Maybe more. It's pointless to try and solve strange behavior of code as long as it has this kind of UB situations.

Comment: "Without any synchronization" does not seem to be an apt characterization, @n.m..  Most of the body of the thread function is protected by a mutex.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ouch, I must be going blind. Everything is indeed mutexed away, But this means there's still no parallelism at all.

Comment: Small note: avoid the use of `signal` and use `sigaction` instead (portability).

Comment: The assignment makes little sense. The problem is user-interaction-bound, the user must enter data for one job at a time, and the job is typically finished much faster than the user gets to start entering the next one. There's nothing to run in parallel. All threads will be waiting for user input almost all the time.

Comment: To make initializing a mutex easier, [per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) you can use `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` and not need to call `pthread_mutex_init()`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &buffer);` => `scanf("%s", buffer);` `write(fd_in, &buffer, strlen(buffer));` => `write(fd_in, buffer, strlen(buffer));` `write(fdGlobal, &buffer, strlen(buffer));` => `write(fdGlobal, buffer, strlen(buffer));` etc

Comment: @JohnBollinger - deleted my prior comment, will delete this one later.

Comment: `0<=i<= N` in your description is an off-by-one error, it would allow N+1 values for i. That said, typically you would set the EOF on the stdin of the program to terminate input, which is often control-D, which isn't an answer but a possible workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has numerous problems revolving around async-signal-safety, buffer sizes, and (non-)concurrency, but by far the most likely reason for the symptom you describe:

> the function read returns 0

is that your belief that the file pointer is not at the end of the file is misplaced.

Indeed, `read()` returning 0 is a positive indicator that the file offset is currently at (or past) the end of the file.  If the file was newly created then I don't see any reason to think that the offset would be anywhere else.  Even when the file already exists, you need to move the file offset back to the beginning to read the data written in the current run of the program.  You could do this with an appropriate call to `lseek()`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your help!